# SQL Server order by different values

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table where `status` can be either `GOLD`, `SILVER`, `ACTIVE` or `INACTIVE`.

I would like to sort by that... in that order and take top X. How can I write that in my query?

Currently I am filling up a list by first querying for `GOLD` and then checking the size of the list, then querying for `SILVER` and again checking the size etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP X *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
  CASE
       WHEN Status = 'GOLD' THEN 4
       WHEN Status = 'SILVER' THEN 3
       WHEN Status = 'ACTIVE'  THEN 2
       WHEN Status = 'INACTIVE' THEN 1
  END DESC
```

Comment: +1 works great - the other option would be to have a separate lookup table for the possible status values, and define a sequence of ordering in that lookup table

Comment: @marc_s: absolutely. I almost memntioned that but didn't want to 'muddy the water'

Comment: I like this quick and easy solution. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

If you were being good, you should really normalize this out to a separate table:

```
statusvalues
id   displaytext sortorder
1    GOLD        10
2    SILVER      20
3    ACTIVE      30
4    INACTIVE    40
```

then store id as your status value on main table. Join from your main table to this one, to get the displaytext and sortorder, and sort appropriately.

NB 1 I leave gaps in the sort order, so that if you have to insert another, you can put it at e.g. 15 without having to change any other values.
NB 2 This means that, if your customer decides that "GOLD" should now display as  "PREMIUM", you change 1 data item value, and your code is unchanged. Might save you a lot of time...!
But this may be overkill - up to you to assess.

Comment: +1. This is the more general way to impose a flexible ordering.

Comment: don't make the `id` column a four byte int, make it a one byte tinyint or just call it `WidgetStatusCode` and make it a char(1).

Comment: I wouldn't make it a char; if you make it numeric, then you can do useful things like "if WidgetStatus < 3 ..." or bitwise operations if you're really clever.

Answer (score -1):

This may help someone. Say you have a table(MyTable) with a column(StatusTypeID) as a foreign key from 'StatusTypes' table. You can implement a procedure to do dynamic sorting like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DynamicSort(@SortOrder int)   
AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN StatusTypeID = @SortOrder then 1
END 

DESC

END
--  exec  DynamicSort 7
```